# sum values of 3d array in c

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d

Based on the test.h file, the function should output 1.000 as the average, but I am getting the wrong value output
the value held in each location of the array is 1.0, 
and 4*5*10 = 200 is total locations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "test.h"

float avgLeaguePlayer(float leagueTeams[4][5][10]);

int main()
{
        while (1)
        {
                printf("MENU\n");
                printf("=====\n");
                printf("  1. Entire League Average Player Rating\n");
                printf("  2. Second Function\n");
                printf("  3. Third Function\n");
                printf("  4. Exit\n");
                printf("Enter selection : ");

                int sel;
                float averagePlayer;
                scanf("%d", &sel);
                switch (sel)
                {
                case 1:
                        averagePlayer = avgLeaguePlayer(leagueTeams);
                        printf("Average Player Rating: %f\n", averagePlayer);
                        break;
                case 2:
                        printf("2\n");
                        // call function 2;
                        break;
                case 3:
                        printf("3\n");
                        // call function 3;
                        break;
                case 4:
                        break;
                default:
                        printf("Invalid Input\n");
                }
                break;
        }
}

float avgLeaguePlayer(float leagueTeams[4][5][10])
{
        int layerOne = 0;
        int layerTwo = 0;
        int layerThree = 0;
        float sum = 0.0;
        float avg = 0.0;

        for (layerOne = 0; layerOne < 4; layerOne++)
        {
                for (layerTwo = 0; layerTwo < 5; layerTwo++)
                {
                        for (layerThree; layerThree < 10; layerThree++)
                        {
                                sum += leagueTeams[layerOne][layerTwo][layerThree];
                        }
                }
        }
        avg = (sum / 200);
        return avg;
}
```

I need help formatting the code to get the correct output. I am new to c, thank you

Answer (score 5):

There is a problem here

```
for(layerThree; layerThree<10; layerThree++)
```

which is fine the first time this nested loop is iterated, because `layerThree` was initialised to `0` when it was defined. But for subsequent iterations, `layerThree` is not reset to `0`. In fact it is `10` so that loop will never iterate again. So the inner loop should be

```
for(layerThree = 0; layerThree < 10; layerThree++)
```

Comment: It is amazing how stupid bugs can hide in plain sight, invisible at first, when quick reading to understand the code.